# How to iterate a dataframe then return rows values in python?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this,

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': ["2004-02-26", "2004-02-27", "2004-03-01",
              "2004-03-02", "2004-03-03", "2004-03-04",
              "2004-03-05", "2004-03-08", "2004-03-09",
              "2004-03-10", "2004-03-11", "2004-03-12"],
     'col2': [-3, 4, 5, 3, -1, 11, 123, 43, -5, 3, -4, -7],
     'col3': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
```

Print it out,

```
              col1  col2  col3
    0   2004-02-26    -3     0
    1   2004-02-27     4     1
    2   2004-03-01     5     0
    3   2004-03-02     3     0
    4   2004-03-03    -1     1
    5   2004-03-04    11     0
    6   2004-03-05   123     0
    7   2004-03-08    43     0
    8   2004-03-09    -5     0
    9   2004-03-10     3     1
    10  2004-03-11    -4     1
    11  2004-03-12    -7     0
```

You can see in `df['col2']`, positive values are seperated by a couple of negative values. I want to select the head and tail row of every group of positive values to a new dataframe. If only one positive row stay in the middle of nagetives I assume the head and tail are the same.

For example,

```
head_date  col2h  co3h    tail_date  col2t  col3t
2004-02-27     4     1     2004-03-02     3     0
2004-03-04    11     0     2004-03-08    43     0
2004-03-10     3     1     2004-03-10     3     1
```

I was thinking select the rows when (i)th row of col2<0 and (i+1)th row of col2>0, return the i+1 row values, and also when (i)th row of col2>0 and (i+1)th row of col2<0, return the i row values. But feels a bit confused.

I hope I described the problem clearly. Really hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
df1 = df.loc[(df['col2'].shift() < 0) & (df['col2'] > 0)].copy()
df1.rename(columns = {'col1': 'head_date', 'col2': 'col2h', 'col3': 'col3h'}, inplace = True)

df2 = df.loc[(df['col2'].shift(-1) < 0) & (df['col2'] > 0)].copy()
df2.rename(columns = {'col1': 'head_date', 'col2': 'col2t', 'col3': 'col3t'})

new_df = pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop = True), df2.reset_index(drop = True)], axis = 1)
```

You get

```
    head_date   col2h   col3h   head_date   col2t   col3t
0   2004-02-27  4       1       2004-03-02  3       0
1   2004-03-04  11      0       2004-03-08  43      0
2   2004-03-10  3       1       2004-03-10  3       1
```